# Power BI get % growth of attendance from month to month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working on a dataset in power BI and I want to find out what the % growth from month to month is. I created a measure to do the calculation for me, it seems correct to me, but it wont work.The error I get is as follows : **The value for 'New People' cannot be determined. Either the column doesn't exist, or there is no current row for this column.**

This is my code:
`NewPeopleMonthlyGrowth% =  VAR PreviousMonthValue = CALCULATE( [New People], FILTER(ALL('Table1'),'Table1'[MonthNumber] = MAX('Table1'[MonthNumber]) -1) ) VAR CurrentMonthValue = SUM('Table1'[New People]) RETURN IF( ISBLANK(PreviousMonthValue), BLANK(), (CurrentMonthValue - PreviousMonthValue) / PreviousMonthValue )`

My table name is Table1. Some of the column names are as follows; New people, Month, MonthNumber(to put months in order), Date, Ministry(I want to know the % of growth in different ministries as well. This includes kids, Sunday services, clubhouse, treehouse).

The error I get is as follows : **The value for 'New People' cannot be determined. Either the column doesn't exist, or there is no current row for this column.**

This is my code:
`NewPeopleMonthlyGrowth% =  VAR PreviousMonthValue = CALCULATE( [New People], FILTER(ALL('Table1'),'Table1'[MonthNumber] = MAX('Table1'[MonthNumber])   -1) ) VAR CurrentMonthValue = SUM('Table1'[New People]) RETURN IF( ISBLANK(PreviousMonthValue), BLANK(), (CurrentMonthValue - PreviousMonthValue) / PreviousMonthValue )`

I am experiencing another problem with my months.
The dataset has the years 2022 and 2023. I am MonthNumber column to put the months in order. For the year 2022, my months display in the correct order, but for 2023, they are still jumbled up.
And When I have the data unfiltered, the months are still jumbled up which is a little confusing. Why would the one year be correct and the other jumbled up.

I attempted to put months in order using power query editor using the below code:
`MonthNumber =  if [Month] = "January" then 1 else if [Month] = "February" then 2 else if [Month] = "March" then 3 else if [Month] = "April" then 4 else if [Month] = "May" then 5 else if [Month] = "June" then 6 else if [Month] = "July" then 7 else if [Month] = "August" then 8 else if [Month] = "September" then 9 else if [Month] = "October" then 10 else if [Month] = "November" then 11 else if [Month] = "December" then 12 else null`

[Month order incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2trW1.jpg)

[Growth% code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrKeN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a calendar/date dimension table? If not, you should. Makes the rest of this much easier to calculate. Here's how I did it (I'm using AdventureWorks, that's why my columns are different):

```
Total Sales = SUM('FactInternetSales'[SalesAmount])
```

And then I can shift backward a month like this:

```
PM Sales = CALCULATE([Total Sales], PREVIOUSMONTH('DimDate'[FullDateAlternateKey]))
```

Then all that's left is to get the delta and divide by the previous month's sales value:

```
Monthly Sales Growth % = DIVIDE([Total Sales] - [PM Sales],[PM Sales])
```

To make this easier to deal with, I created a "MonthYear" column in my date dimension like this:

```
MonthYear = DATE([CalendarYear],[MonthNumberOfYear],1)
```

Then I just added a matrix viz to my canvas, [MonthYear] on rows and [Total Sales], [PM Sales], and [Monthly Sales Growth %] on values.

the Month/Year thing ... that's why I used the expression above... because mine is a date, it automatically sorts in the proper order. I just set the date format for the column to be *mmmm yyyy*.

I find it infinitely easier to start with simple measures and then reuse them when creating new measures.=)